# saving images from html5 camera

Tags: html, image, camera, live-streaming

My question is, how can I save COMPLETE images from a HTML5 camera live stream?

Here you can find me current code ( I'm a JavaScript beginner ):

```
    const video = document.getElementById('video');
    const canvas = document.getElementById('faceImage');


    const hdConstraints = {
        audio: false,
        video: { width: { min: 1280 }, height: { min: 720 } }
    };

    var options = { mimeType: 'video/webm' };
    navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(hdConstraints, options)
        .then(
            (stream) => {
                video.srcObject = stream;
                video.play();

            setInterval(function() {
                    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
                    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 1280, 720);
                    var data = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');

                    ws.send(data);
            }, 1000);

            }
        );
```

With this code on the server side I receive not complete jpeg images ( only 10% of the canvas is on the picture and the other parts are blank).

So my question is, how can I correct this code to send only complete images to the server ?

thanks

Comment: Why are you using Base-64 encoding?  Your web socket connection supports binary just fine.

Comment: Thanks, that helped. I'm not sure why, but without base64 it is working